# how to change code to prevent df error when knitting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, debugging

In R I want to create a bar chart where I pick out 12 most common bird species and illustrate the number of observations per species and calender week in a bar chart. data_artportal has 30 columns and I therefore need to extract data from the "artnamn" column and the "startdatum" (start date) column.

This is my data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sj1jrd6qiigdwe4/artportalen.csv?dl=0

This is my code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

df %>%
  filter(artnamn %in% top12) %>%
  select(id, artnamn, startdatum) %>%
  mutate(startdatum = as.Date(startdatum, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         week.no = isoweek(startdatum)) %>%
  group_by(artnamn, week.no) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(week.fct = ifelse(week.no == 52, -1, week.no),
         week.order = fct_reorder(as.factor(week.no), week.fct)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(week.order, n, fill = artnamn)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") + facet_wrap(.~artnamn)
```

When I run the whole code by clicking on "Knit", output should be a Github document, it gives me the error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `Artnamn %in% top12`.
Caused by error:
! object 'top12' not found
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% ggplot(aes(week.order, n, fill = Artnamn))
 16. Artnamn %in% top12
Execution halted
```

After reading on various forums on the same topic, I added this code to my code above:

```
adult <- read.csv2('artportalen.csv')
df <- read.csv("artportalen.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- read.csv("artportalen.csv")
```

However, I am stil getting the same error. What can I do?

Comment: Please don't add your data as a link, but instead edit your question to include reproducible code. Links often go dead over time, many users are discouraged from clicking them, etc and it is not good for the long-term posterity of the site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From your question/code is not clear, how you calculated `top12`. And the error:

```r
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `Artnamn %in% top12`.
Caused by error:
! object 'top12' not found
```

tells us, that `top12` (which is used in filter) is not defined

```r
df %>%
  filter(artnamn %in% top12) %>%
```

My attempt:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

df <- read.csv(file = "/home/sapi/Downloads/artportalen.csv")
```

Let's define `top12` as the 12 most frequent `Artnamn`

```r
top12 <- df |>
  group_by(Artnamn) |>
  count() |>
  arrange(desc(n)) |>
  head(12) |>
  ungroup() |>
  subset(select = -n) |>
  as.list()
```

Probably your definition is a bit different, but you have to include it in your workbook chunks prior to filtering.

And finally your code:

```r
df |>
  filter(Artnamn %in% top12[[1]]) |>
  select(Id, Artnamn, Startdatum) |>
  mutate(startdatum = as.Date(Startdatum, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         week.no = lubridate::isoweek(Startdatum)) |>
  group_by(Artnamn, week.no) |>
  summarise(n = n()) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(week.fct = ifelse(week.no == 52, -1, week.no),
         week.order = fct_reorder(as.factor(week.no), week.fct)) |>
  ggplot(aes(week.order, n, fill = Artnamn)) +
  geom_col(position = "stack") + facet_wrap(.~Artnamn)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>